# How to load flat file with dynamic columns with different datatype into oracle database?

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql

I want to load a flat file into oracle Database. This flat file may be generated from table A or table B or table C.

So when I am loading this file into oracle table , I am exactly not sure how many columns and what data type is column has that flat file has ( depends on whether it is generated from table A or table B or table C ).

So, pls let me know the generic method, technique to load variable column length file into oracle database.

Example:

- Table A

  `1 | 2 | 3 | 4`
- Table B

  `1 | XYZ | 3 | 4 | 5 | XXX`
- Table 3

  `xxx | 2013-09-28 | 10.0`

So, here each table has variable columns and different datatype. How can I load these file into oracle database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there only three possible layouts?  Are the number of columns and the data types fixed for each table?  Is there something in the file that indicates which sort of file it is?  Is it possible to add a header row that would contain this information?

Comment: Does one file contain records with all three possible formats?  If so, that is going to be pretty hard to import w/o writing some code.

Comment: As I understand it you have one file, this file has a single format but that format may be one of 3 depending on where the file was extracted from. This is really simple to solve. Don't call the file the same name for each table. Call it something different if it was extracted from table A or table B.

Comment: Are you trying to each type of file into one table, or a different table depending on the file source?

Comment: Here format of the file is not fixed to above 3 table. It varies. One table may have 10 columns and another may have 3 columns. How to create a temp table with variable columns (data types also )to load the flat file data

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use SQLLoader to load files into tables.
Say we have created three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA(
  col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int 
);

CREATE TABLE tableB(
  col1 int, col2 varchar2(100), col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 varchar2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE tableC(
  col1 varchar2(100), col2 date, col3 number(10,2)
);
```

I am assuming that the file has always records in one format only (one of 3 possible formats).
In such a case, you can create 3 different control files for each format:
**format_a.ctl**

```
load data
 infile 'c:\tmp\test\file.txt'
 into table tableA
 fields terminated by "|"         
 ( col1, col2, col3, col4 )
```

**format_b.ctl**

```
load data
 infile 'c:\tmp\test\file.txt'
 into table tableB
 fields terminated by "|"         
 ( col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 )
```

**format_c.ctl**

```
infile 'c:\tmp\test\file.txt'
 into table tableC
 fields terminated by "|"         
 ( col1 , 
   col2 date 'yyyy-mm-dd',
   col3 )
```

Then create a simple script that detects a format of the file and uploads data using an appropriate control file - this is an example for Windows environment:

```
@echo off
set filename=file.txt
IF NOT EXIST   %filename%  GOTO error

findstr /M "\|.*\|.*\|.*\|.*\|" file.txt
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO formatB

findstr /M "\|.*\|.*\|" file.txt
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO formatA

findstr /M "\|.*\|" file.txt
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO formatC

:error
Echo Error: file %filename% doesn't exist or doesn't match any proper format
goto end

:formatA
set ctl_file=format_a
goto import

:formatB
set ctl_file=format_b
goto import

:formatc
set ctl_file=format_c
goto import

:import
echo Import using: %ctl_file%
sqlldr test/test@//192.168.2.51:1521/orcl control=%ctl_file%.ctl log=%ctl_file%.log
:end
```

In this line:

```
sqlldr test/test@//192.168.2.51:1521/orcl control=%ctl_file%.ctl log=%ctl_file%.log
```

test/test@ is a database user `test` having password `test`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the replay.

Here format of the file is not fixed to above 3 table. It varies. One table may have 10 columns and another may have 3 columns.

How to create a temp table with variable columns (data types also )to load the flat file data

Comment: 0down voteaccept 



Pls let me know whether the above problem can be resolved. I can use SQL*Loader once the table is creatd. But the problem is how to create a table with dynamic data.

The input file comes at run time with variable column and datatypes.So I cannot create a table statically with known datatypes and number of cilumns.

Pls help.